# Link text file with the latest date stamp to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a MS access which I have link a file called **CSAT**. Everyday I overwrite this file with the latest CSAT and run a query. I their a way to autmatically overwrite or Linked the file with the latest CSAT ?
Here is a Printscreen of the CSAT Folder. Its a cvs file.
[image: Files with name + date]

Comment: Yes, you can alter the `.Connect` property of a link to point to a different file.    But you need to know *which* file to target.  Have you worked out a method to identify which of the CSV files is the "latest"?

Comment: The latest file will be csat_survey_MM_DD_2015 or it can use the date modified of the file.

Comment: I meant have you created the VBA code to identify which CSV file is the latest?  Seems to me you need to do that first.  Then worry about modifying the link property.

Comment: No, I did it manually, but I will research on that.